# How to create this Setting Layout in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

I want to create a settting UI like this in android:

[image]

Questions:

1. How to create the layout? I believe it's a Vertical LinearLayout containing some of TextView with Divider set, is that right?
2. How to create sub-textview? (see the image above)
3. How to create a checkbox which aligned at right? (again, see the image above)
4. Look at the image above, the "Keypress popup" can be clicked and it will show up a dialog. How to create a clickable TextView? I have tried giving `android:onClick` on the TextView, but nothing happened when I clicked the TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) will help you to implement all these very easily. Go through [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-quick-preferences-tutorial.html) and [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-preferences-activity-example/) tutorials.

[PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) should be used post Honeycomb.

Comment: Wow, thx a lot. I didn't know there is special Activity for this. What is the main difference between PreferenceActivity and PreferenceFragment?

Comment: First you don't need to extend your Activity from PreferenceActivity which restrict to extend it from any other Activity if required. And The fragment can show settings in a two-pane presentation mode when on larger screens. As docs says, It is easy to create a hierarchy of preferences (that can be shown on multiple screens) via XML, For these reasons, it is recommended to use this PreferenceFragment (as a superclass) to deal with preferences in applications.